# Excel Merge cells if other cell matches

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

Merge cells if another cell has two or more of same value:  My data has two or more records that are the same except for one cell: example A1 Name=Joe, A2=Joe but B1=Tuesday, B2=Wednesday.  I need to show one row A1=Joe and B1=Tuesday,Wednesday.  I can create another row like C1=B1&B2, but how do I make it loop through A and if there is a matching record, merge the two values that are in B. I think it will be something like putting into C1,C2, C3... =IF(A1=A2..., B1&B2, " ")  But instead of A2 how can it loop through all A then merger the results of B for matching records?

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution which does not require the use of Array Formulas, and should be able to loop through all possibilities.  Again, it will require your raw data to be sorted by Name (so that all Names are grouped together), then add this formula to the column directly after your Raw data (I’m assuming C2)

```
=IF(A1<>A2,B2,C1&","&B2)
```

This will Join everything above it with a comma, and reset the join every time the Name changes.  By this manor the one with the data you want will always be against the last instance of the Name.  We can find the last instance using the results from Steps 2 & 3 in my previous answer, and then index that against the results from the above formula, so..

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2)+MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0) -1)
```

In the above I'm assuming the name you want the final answer to is in Cell A2

Comment: After playing around with all your excellent advise your short IF statement above is close to all I need.  The "=IF(A1<>A2,B2,C1&","&B2)" adds the next day if the records are for the same person, but it adds the second day to the persons second record (then 3rd etc.).  I understand that is how it should be when looping but is there a way to make the first record receive the additinal days.  Reason: The sheet that reads this data does a lot more with =MATCH and OFFSET and the cell which needs this information must read the first record.

Comment: I've been trying to adjust your script to show the multiple days on the first record but your script is pretty cut & dry simple and I do not see a way.  Is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can.  If you keep the short `IF` statement where it is (you hide the column if you don't wish to see it) then add the second formula above (the one that starts with `=INDEX...`) on the column right next to it, this will make the full result appear on every record.  You can limit that to only the first by adding the followng in front of the INDEX statement `IF(A1=A2,"",INDEX...`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution.  (I'm hoping I'v understood your setup correctly)

Step 1) Separate out all your unique names in column A into a new sheet, again into column A on your new sheet - if your using excel 2007 or later you can just copy the whole column over then use the Remove Duplicates tool

Step 2) On your new sheet add the following into column B2.  This will count the number of occurrences of each Name.  (Note: I'm assuming your Raw data is in Sheet1, and the new copy to process in Sheet2)

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,$A2)
```

Step 3) Add the following to C3.  This will find the row number of the first occurrence of the name.  (IMPORTANT:  this means your Raw data will need to have a Sort applied to ensure the Names all appear grouped together)

```
=MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5,0)
```

Step 4) On Columns D to J you'll need to add the following Array Formula.  If you've not worked with Array Formula before then: (i) select cells D2:J2 (ii) ensuring D2 is the active cell (iii) enter the formula below into the formula bar (iv) press ctrl+shift+enter

This takes your data in column B offsets it by the first row occurrence (Step 3), re-sized by the count of names (Step 2), and transposed (which reverses rows for columns)

```
=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5,C2-1,0,B2))
```

That may suit you needs as is, but if you insist on comma separating the days, then you can add this to K2, and just hide columns B to J.

```
=IF(ISNA(D2),"",D2)&IF(ISNA(E2),"",","&E2)&IF(ISNA(F2),"",","&F2)&IF(ISNA(G2),"",","&G2)&IF(ISNA(H2),"",","&H2)&IF(ISNA(I2),"",","&I2)&IF(ISNA(J2),"",","&J2)
```

I have assumed that you'll never need to join more than 7 values together (eg the 7 days of the week).  But if you do, then you'll have to extend the Array formula onto more columns.  If you don't have a set max, then it may be worth investigating a VBA solution.

Comment: Steps 1,2&3 worked fine (step 3 I put into C2)  but step 4 just returns 0.  The worse part is that I will defiantly be needing more than 7 the number is unlimited.  So, I am going to add VBA to the tags and hope someone can get me on track.

Comment: @user745778 your right I meant C2 for step 3.  I found you another solution using formulas, which is a little simplier.  I've posted it as another answer